# Change padding-margin in wordpress css

Tags: margin, padding

I'm using following code to change the margin-bottom. It's working in inspect mode but actually not working.

```css
body .container-wrapper, body .body-wrapper #undefined-sticky-wrapper {
     margin-bottom: 0px; 
}
```

website: www.gtctrust.com

[In Inspect Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzHyR.jpg)

[Actual view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm50b.png)

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you lost a ',' befor '#undefined-sticky-wrapper' in the css file.Hope this will help you.

Comment: Please have a try.I'm waiting for your feedback.  :-)

Comment: I have konwn the reason.Plese find the dom which id is undefined-sticky-wrapper and remove the "margin-bottom:43px;" of its style.

Comment: "find the dom"- I don't get it

Comment: dom means Document Object Model